# How to open a program using code

Tags: vb.net, button, visual-studio-2013

I want to open `Chrome` when I click a button in my program. Let's say the button is called btnChrome.

How would I do that?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This site isn't a code writing service. Please take a moment to re-read the guidelines for asking questions here in the [Help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help). But sometimes you have luck ...

Comment: As it stands the question is too broad. You need to actually do some work yourself and then come back should you find yourself stuck but only after you've researched the problem. As it stands you've done nothing. Start with Googling your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Process.Start Method in a quick and dirty way. This starts the process resource that is specified by the parameter containing process start information (for example, the file name of the process to start) and associates the resource with a new Process component.

For further information see also: [Process.Start Method (ProcessStartInfo)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w4h05yb(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
Public Class Form1
  Private Sub btnChrome_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnChrome.Click
    '--- Open browser
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("chrome.exe", "www.help-info.de")
  End Sub
End Class
```